# Kafka InputDStream repartitioning in spark streaming-Parallelism

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

As part of spark performance tuning task. **Spark** stream application (written in Java) has input from kafka receiver- topic and push the output to other **kafka** topic.Spark application runs with 13 executors with 3gb memory and 4 vcores per executor. Kafka topic is created with 13 partition and replication factor is set one.Necessity of spark stream application is to take messages and process it with throughput of 1500 messages per second. But, I find parallelism is not happening at executor level.My doubts and needs are

- Can Kafka InputDstream(per se 130 message in one batch) from topic can be repartition(split) to each executor(so 130 message is split among 13 executors(JVM) i.e., 10 message per executor)?
- If it is completely possible, how it can be achieved? any reference or methods/classes of api?
- Bottle neck of my application is that all 130 message is processing at all 13 executors (No parallelism happening)